# terminal unix command find problem with setting up modes

Tags: macos, terminal

I have trouble constructing a single find line to do the following:
find all files in the current dir and sub-dir with name ending with ~. or star and end with '#'.I think I have made a fundamental mistake but not so sure after 2 hours of thinking.

This is what I came up with and it does not seem to work:
find -name '[#]*' -a -name '*[~#]'

macOSX terminal

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `ls` and `grep` to find all the files ending with either ~ or #

```
ls * | grep -E "*.(\~|#)"
```

`ls -R *` will show all files in the current dir and sub-dir;

`grep -E` will search for lines matching a regular expression;

`"*.(\~|#)"` will match all lines ending with either `~` or `#` (note that you'll need to escape the `~` with `\` since it's a special character).